# Need help to understand some terminology in discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, terminology

1) "Suppose that f is a function from set A to itself."
2) "(...)from the set of real numbers to itself."

In these two sentences, what does "to itself" mean? Is this the same as saying that 1) is f: A --> A and that 2) is f: R --> R? This is not explained in the book that I use.

Comment: Your guess is right. The only other interpretation of “itself” I can think of would be the function $f$, and that makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Yeah! That's what it means

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $f$ is a function from $A$ into $A$.  The function need not be onto.